# how to make a separate log file for bind service in rsyslog?

Tags: 12.04, logging, bind, rsyslog

I installed bind9 for name service on ubuntu12.04. Now for debugging its errors in name resolving.

I need to make separate log file for it like `/var/log/name.log`. I searched too many for rsyslog, but as i search more and more, i mixed up in configurations.

How can i make separate log file for bind service by rsyslog?

Comment: What version of rsyslog are you running?  The config options change dramatially, but basically you can use the imfile module to read the log file from your Bind server and send the logs with a tag to wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

For separate the bind9 service log file, just need to adding `logging` section in the `name.conf.local` file as below:

```
logging {
channel default_file {
    file "/var/log/named/default.log" versions 5 size 5m;
    severity notice;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel general_file {
    file "/var/log/named/general.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic; //notice;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel database_file {
    file "/var/log/named/database.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel queries_file {
    file "/var/log/named/queries.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel client_file {
    file "/var/log/named/client.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel resolver_file {
    file "/var/log/named/resolver.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
};
channel security_file {
    file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 10m;
    severity dynamic;
    print-time yes;
};
category security { security_file; };
category default{ default_file;  };
category general { general_file; };
category database { database_file; };
};
```

[Here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/logging.html) describe the meaning of each word in this section.